# Time to first byte very slow - 1.5 minutes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have been having intermittent problems where TTFB being very slow.  In some cases it is over a minute in other cases it is seconds.  In other cases the page refuses to open.  Note this is when I am opening our SharePoint 2013 Home page, but other pages have been experiencing the same issue....

Our admins say there is nothing wrong with our servers and it is my Site Collection only that is having an issue.  How can I further troubleshoot.  Note I do not have access to Central Admin.

Comment: - Do you get this issue even when you open other pages like Site Settings? - Would you also take a look at the what is taking time using Developers

Comment: Is this the first page pull of the day?

Comment: Now no pages are loading no matter what site I retrieve...Oddly I can get into the sitemanager.aspx page and that is it..This occurs no matter what time of day I try to retrieve the page..Occasionally though like magic all the pages in the site begin to work (not/slow can load).  However, most of today they can not load..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears CPU was at 100%.  Once they cleared the Proc Cache all was fine...Am curious to know though what caused the high usage.